# Intetcept JdbcTemplate without using AOP or wrapper

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

What all I want to do is automatically collect statistical values from DB for each DML or DQL has been executed in Spring or Spring Boot application.

Take Oracle for example, if I execute a query - `select 1 from dual`, then I can execute a next query - `select * from v$mtstat a, v$statnameb where a.statistic# = b.statistic#` to retrieve statistical values for current session.

Therefore, once I use `JdbcTemplate` or `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` to access DB (*SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE*), I also want to collect those statistical values initiatively for further analysis.

I have surveyed several techniques such as **datasource-proxy** or **P6Spy**, but they didn't meet my requirement.

So does anyone knows how to achieve this without using AOP or wrapping it?
Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest using CustomBeanFactoryPostProcessor and custom annotation to wrap the method of your interest in proxy if you don't want to use AOP, but you don't want to wrap so I am out of ideas. Good luck in finding a solution.

Comment: @improbable Thanks for your reply in advance. I wonder know if with the help of AOP, can this problem be solved much easier?

Comment: The whole purpose of AOP is to do something before method execution or after. So I guess, yes.